# VAR_Constant in Case structure in FXCPU / GXWorks2

Tags: plc

I have a weird problem in GX Works 2 (Learning the ropes)...

I am trying to create a simple state machine with a couple different states. But I do want to use variable names for each of the states, but can't get this to work.

`Step0` is a variable constant that represents `0` and this is my code:

```
    CASE iCount  OF
            Step0: 
                Test := "Step 0";
            1: 
                Test := "Step 1";
            2: 
                Test := "Step 2";
            3: 
                iCount := -1;
            ELSE
                Test := "Default case";
    END_CASE;

    iCount := iCount + 1;
```

I get a simple `Parse error` on `Step0` in the first line. If i replace `Step0` with `0` it works flawlessly. Both `iCount` and `Step0` is Signed Words.

Any ideas?

## EDIT

The relevant quote from the manual:

> Data types that can be used in  of CASE
>   conditional statement The data types that can be specified as the
>    in the CASE conditional statement are the integer
>   type (INT) and double precision integer type (DINT). The word devices
>   and word type or double word type labels can be specified.

I think it means that I can infact use WORD datatypes (wich **is** a INT).

Comment: I'm almost sure that Structured Text (like other popular languages) expects "selectors" to be (ranges of) **"immediate" values**, i.e. literal numbers or, at most, names corresponding to user defined _enumerated types_. I'm trying to find some reference... Why don't you just want to use an immediate 0?

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean with `immediate 0`, but I would like to use named variables to enhance the readability of the code (without the use of comments)... Check my edit for the relevant text from the manual I'm trying to desipher :)

Comment: I mean immediate values (e.g. literal `0`) as opposed to **expressions**. A variable (even if constant) is indeed an expression that in this case evaluates to an INT or DINT value. I'm afraid the compiler cannot parse expressions as selectors, even if they are of correct numeric type. If you like symbolic names, use enumerated types rather than variables.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean. I will look up how to create enumerated types, and if it works and you post it as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As selectors, try using enumerated types rather than variables:

```
TYPE
    STEP: (STEP_0, STEP_1, STEP_2, STEP_3);
END_TYPE

CASE iCount OF
    STEP_0: 
        Test := "Step 0";
    STEP_1: 
        Test := "Step 1";
    STEP_2: 
        Test := "Step 2";
    STEP_3: 
        iCount := -1;
    ELSE
        Test := "Default case";
END_CASE;

iCount := iCount + 1;
```

Comment: Hi, TYPE does not work in FXCPU / GX Works2, I get `The undefined label 'TYPE' is being used. C1028`.  :/ I do appreciate the effort to help though :) I will keep looking into it...

Comment: GX Works may have its own syntax or most likely it just doesn't support enums. I'm afraid you'll have to use the good old code comments! :)

Comment: You are right :( It is not possible to use constant variables in Case structures in FXCPU :O :/